# print an entire table in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow, datacolumn

I'm trying to print the content of a `DataTable`, starting with the column headers, followed by the content of the table tupples.

```
output.Add($"Table : [{dataTable.TableName}]");
string strColumnNames = "";
foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
{
    if (strColumnNames == "")
         strColumnNames = col.ColumnName.PadLeft(col.MaxLength - col.ColumnName.Length);  // (*)
    else strColumnNames = strColumnNames + "|" + 
                          col.ColumnName.PadLeft(col.MaxLength - col.ColumnName.Length);  // (*)
}
output.Add($"[{strColumnNames}]");


foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
{
    string temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < dataRow.ItemArray.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            temp = dataRow.ItemArray[i].ToString();                          // (**)
        else temp += "|" + dataRow.ItemArray[i].ToString();                  // (**)
    }
    output.Add($"[{temp}]");
}
```

The `(*)` parts in this code are using the `MaxLength` property of the `DataColumn`s maximum length in order to get a column-like output.

I would like to do the same in the `(**)` parts, but I don't know how to access the corresponding `DataColumn`, starting from the `dataRow` object.

Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: No need to start from dataRow if you use dataTable... `dataTable.Columns[i].MaxLength`

Comment: What is `output` ? Won't you simplify the process by converting the DataTable to a CSV string before outputing it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the `dataTable` instance available. `dataTable.Columns[i]` should give you the appropriate `DataColumn`.

Answer (score 1):

`Datatable` has already been instantiated here. If you want to print the datacolumn you should use `dataTable.Column[i]` for the appropriate column.